# How to automate exporting a report from QuickBooks daily?

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

### Goal

- My goal is to **automate** exporting a small list out of my QuickBooks daily.
- I came across a plug-in call TPE ( [Transaction Pro Exporter](http://transactionpro.com/products/01TxnExportDemo.asp) )
- It allow me to connect to my QuickBooks, and export any lists I wanted, any way I wanted - in term of details
- On top of that, they allow me to specify the arguments as command line arguments : [TPE Documentation](http://bscdownload.com/downloads/Command_Line_Parameters_TPE.htm)
- I followed the TPE documentation and did everything as I should. I edit the shortcut of TPE, and set the

> Target = "C:\Program Files (x86)\01 Transaction Pro Exporter 5.0\Transaction Pro Exporter 5.0.exe"

Arguments are :

- /AUTORUN 1
- /TXN=Item List
- /EXPORTFORMAT=CSV
- /FILENAME=Desktop:\output.csv
- /QB_COMPANY_PATH=C:\Users\bheng\Desktop\Company Inc - 2015-01-08 - 7pm.QBW
- /NOEXCEL

### See here :

[image]

### Questions

- As you guys can see that I set `F5` to trigger my application.
- After I run it, everything seem to works fine, but I couldn't find the file that I export.
- As part of the arguement, I did this `/FILENAME=Desktop:\output.csv` so that I should see `output.csv` on my Desktop, but I didn't. :(

Can anyone tell what did I do wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The error is in here:`/FILENAME=Desktop:\output.csv`
Making a sub-folder should fix it.

> Ex. Let's make a sub-folder called `test`

Then, it would look something like this `/FILENAME=Desktop:\test\output.csv`

Now, after hitting F5 , it should work like a charm.